# How can i fetch dynamic data from database based on selected language.?

Tags: database, laravel

Hi i am working on a project in `laravel 7.0`, in back-end i have a table called `Posts` which contains 2 text language input one in `french` and the other is `arabic` added by the back-end `application`.
what i am trying to do is when the user uses the `French Language` i want the `title_fr` to be displayed on the view and same thing in `Arabic language` the title should be `title_ar`.

> P.S data are stored in `French` and `Arabic`

I have tried the similar solution given in an other similar question but none of it worked in my case!

Any idea how i might get this to work ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have tow columns in db ? title_fr and title_ar?

Comment: are  you using a laravel-translatable ?

Comment: @OMR yes i have 2 columns in post table one is title_fr and title_ar

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to below. We have a model `Post`, this model has an attribute `title`. I also assume that you have an attribute that will return user's language from the `User` model.

```
class Post extends Model 
{
   public function getTitleAttribute(): string
   {
      return Auth::user()->language === 'fr' ? $this->title_fr : $this->title_ar;
   }
}
```

FYI above is just a demo on what can be done. For a full blow solution I would recommend decorator pattern.

Also it might be worth considering using morph for things like that. You can have a service provider that will initiate the morph map for you post model relevant to the language that user has, I.e.

```
Class ModelProvider {
   Protected $models = [
      ‘fr’ => [
           ‘post’ => App/Models/Fr/Post::class,
      ],
      ‘ar’ => [
           ‘post’ => App/Models/Ar/Post::class,
      ]
   ];

   Public function boot() {
       $language = Auth::user()->Settings->language;

       Relation::morphMap($This->models[$language]);
   }
}
```

Afterwards you just need to call to Relation::getMorphModel(‘post’) to grab Post class that will return correct language.

I.e. App/Models/Fr/Post can have a an attribute title:

```
Public function getTitleAttribute(): string {
   Return $this->title_fr;
}
```

For example above you would also want to utilise interfaces to make sure that all models follow the same contract, something below would do the trick:

```
Interface I18nPostInterface {
   Public function getTitleAttribute(): string
}
```

Also, depending on the database you use, to store titles (and other language data) in a JSON format in the database. MySQL 8 has an improve support for JSON data, but there are limitations with that.

Comment: how can i return user's language from the User model ? I am using laravel localozation, inside the directory resources/lang i have two JSON files ar.json and fr.json.

Comment: I would need to know how you let user select a language to know how to answer your question.Are you storing language in a session or in the database table? Btw, me grabbing language from `User` model is me trying to imaging what you may have.

Comment: I am using laravel localization and using JSON files and session in Middleware. inside the directory resources/lang i have two JSON files ar.json and fr.json. and in my balde view i have 2 <a/> tags one for ar.json and the other for fr.json when the user select the Fr link the app brings the fr.json and same for the ar.json

Comment: ok, in that case you can grab language based on url. I can get back to you later about this if you like

Comment: yes please because i am new to laravel can u explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

So I was Able to fetch data from my database based on the Language selected by the user.
Like i said before I have a table called `Posts` and has columns `id`,`title_fr` and `title_ar`. I am using `laravel Localization`.

Inside my `PostController` in the index `function` i added this code:

```
    public function index()
{
    //
    $post = Post::all();
    $Frtitle = post::get()->pluck('title_fr');
    $Artitle = post::get()->pluck('title_ar');

    return view('post.index',compact('post','Frtitle','Artitle'));
}
```

> if anyone has a better way then mine please let me know, i am sure
>   there is a better way.